# Glue a sample at -40 Degrees

Tags: metals, temperature

I would need to stick two opposite edges of a sample on two small metallic plates (as it were a bridge).
The sample is Silicon and on top an high temperure superconductor which is Temperature sensitive. This means that the procedure is done at -40 degrees maximum.

I tried to use U300 epoxy, but this does not work since the reaction of the two components is not activated at this low temperature.

Do you know a special glue that can work? Please be aware that I will perform experiments at few Kelvin, so the glue (or whatever) should be cryo.

Comment: Have you looked into UV curing adhesives?

Comment: Can you specify which units? Probably Fahrenheit or Celsius, which both at -40 mean the same temperature, but maybe you ment a more exotic unit.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a liquid whose melting point is slightly above $-40\,\mathsf{^{\circ}C}$, pre-chill it to just above its melting point, then squirt some on to your bridge (in a controlled environment below $-40\,\mathsf{^{\circ}C}$) and let it freeze, it *might* form a cement that will hold the bridge together.  Heptanol has about the right melting point, but I have no idea what the safety requirements for handling it are.

(Idea based on the work of Jean-Robert Murat, who was using fresh water as a glue to stick strain gauges to Arctic sea ice in the early 1980s.)